# sometimes ajax listener is not getting called in JSF commandlink

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, dojo, ajax4jsf

I searched all over net and tried many things but nothing is working out...
In my .xhtml page there are 7 links which are JSf command links as below,

```
    <h:commandLink id="HeaderLink" value="Header">
        <f:ajax render="orderHeaderVOString" 
            onevent="updateHeaderVO"
            listener="#{OrderMBean.getOrderHeaderData}" />
    </h:commandLink>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <h:commandLink id="orderLinesLink" value="Lines">
        <f:ajax render="orderLinesVOString" 
            onevent="updateLinesVO"
            listener="#{OrderMBean.getOrderLinesData}" />
    </h:commandLink>
```

input hidden fields as below

```
    <h:inputHidden value="#{directCustViewOrderMBean.headerVOString}"
        id="orderHeaderVOString" />
    <h:inputHidden value="#{directCustViewOrderMBean.linesVOString}"
        id="orderLinesVOString" />
```

and javascript methods as below

```
    function updateHeaderVO(data) {
          if (data.status == 'success') {
        var orderHeaderVOString =    document.getElementById('viewOrderForm:orderHeaderVOString').value;
            var parsedJSON = eval("(" + orderHeaderVOString + ")");
             alert("success");
             }}
```

my problem is when i keep navigating through the pages after changing some 4 to 5 pages,
i am getting the error "syntax error: unexpected end of input". This is because listener method is not getting called and the data inside 'viewOrderForm:orderHeaderVOString' will be empty. why sometimes its is getting called and sometimes its not getting called?

Comment: Use JSON.parse instead of eval as JSON.parse will throw a SyntaxError exception if the string to parse is not valid JSON, if you use eval you are evaluating every possible JS expression.

Comment: Also open firbug or any other developer tools and verify if the ajax request is made or not.

Comment: Do you have nested `<h:forms/>`?

Comment: I have tried with the JSON.parse also,still same problem exist.I am nesting this in <h:forms/> only

Comment: i have put System.out.println(); in the first line of Mbean method and verifying whether ajax call is made or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, its working fine now
problem was with

```
<h:inputHidden feilds
```

as each time i navigate through the pages the value keep residing in the hidden feilds so the ajax call was not happening.
now i am nullfying the hidden feilds each time.so its working fine,ajax call is happening.